# A sorta extentsion on a method java

Tags: java, methods

So i'm creating a API to java and i need a extention like thing on my method. Example:

```
someMethod().getName();
```

Something like that. Anyone know how?

Comment: not really sure what you mean. but what you are doing is not really an 'extension'. what you are doing, is calling toString() on the returned result of someMethod()

Comment: It was just a example. I could use another one. Like getWorld().getName();

Comment: It is called **method chaining**.

Comment: that doesn't change that it's just calling a method on the result of the first one. it's method chaining, as Christian said.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is something called **method chaining**. Let's put this example:

```
obj.methodOne().methodTwo()
```

This will call `methodTwo()` from the object returned by the call `obj.methodOne()`, so you can think the above chain as if it were this:

```
(obj.methodOne()).methodTwo()
```

Let's say you have this class:

```
public class MyClass2 {
    public int methodTwo() {...}
}
```

Then, to be able to call `methodTwo` from the result of `obj.methodOne()`, the method `methodOne()` should *return* an instance of the class `MyClass2`:

```
public class MyClass1 {
    public MyClass2 methodOne() {
        return new MyClass2(); // returns instance of 'MyClass2'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but this may help

```
class Foo {
    Object someMethod() {
        ...
        return new Object() {
            public String toString() {
                return "Bar";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you're doing is returning an anonymous class and that overrides toString().
You can read more about anonymous classes here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unable to express your question.
1) If you want to have `toString()` method in a class you can do the following:

```
public class XYZ
{
    //Your properties and methods
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        //Manipulate what you want to return as a String
        return a_string;
    }
}
```

2) You want to call a method on the result of a method.  **Method Chaining**

```
class XYZ
{
    //Your properties and methods
    public ABC getABC()
    {
        return an_ABC_object;
    }
}

class ABC
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // do some work or print something
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        XYZ xyz=new XYZ();
        xyz.getABC().doSomething();
    }
}
```